# 401 Unauthorized REST API in lightning web component salesforce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, salesforce, fetch-api, lwc

I'm trying to execute query using REST API, in a lightning web component.
the request in Postman returning result with success (enabling Follow Authorization header)
but in the JavaScript in lightning web component it returns 401 Unauthorized
the code in the java script is a follow :

```
let sessionId = 'tokken';
let baseUrl = window.location.origin;
let header = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionId,
};
if (sessionId) {
    let options = {
        method: "GET",
        mode: 'no-cors',
        redirect: 'follow',
        headers: header,
    };
    fetch(baseUrl + '/services/data/v50.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account', options).then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        if (!response.ok) {
            // throw Error(JSON.stringify(response));
        } else {
            return response.json();
        }
    }).then((repos) => {
        console.log(repos, repos);
    });
}
```

am I missing something ?

Comment: Where are you getting that session Id?

Comment: the session id that I'm getting is fine

Answer (score 1):

Since you can not pass the value `Authorization` to `no-cors` mode, you will need to [add CORS configuration](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.extend_code_cors.htm&type=5) in your SalesForce as safe endpoint where they let you make a call.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send Authorization header with "no-cors" mode.

`mode: "no-cors"`only allows a limited set of headers in the request:

```
Accept
Accept-Language
Content-Language
Content-Type with a value of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain
```

Comment: so what I should change to be able to send the authorization ? what mode should I put ?

Comment: Just delete this line. It'll be use default mode which is "cors" mode. If you get cors error use [this extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf/related?hl=en) for fix it.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help, but the client also have to install this extension to make this request work form him, right ?